# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '1' of undefined

Tags: javascript, json, google-maps-api-3

trying to fiddle with an app, getting this error "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '1' of undefined "in dev tools console. i'm pretty sure it's because of the json i'm pulling and the proxy i'm using are not talking to each other correctly. seriously n00b question, i truly don't understand what's going on in the document. i also see that there are ALOT of similar questions like this, so i'm guessing they're pretty localized and not great for the community. still important to me though...i'd like to learn what's going on in the code, not just fix the problem. you can check it out here: http://dev.bowdenweb.com/busfinder.html  i did put it up on jsfiddle, but it wasn't rendering correctly. thanks for any and all advice!

Comment: `loadBusesIntoMap` seems to be the root of the problem. Investigate there see what you can find...

Comment: can you elaborate? and i don't mean, fix it for me...i mean, how did you make the connection between the two? thanks

Comment: Chrome developer tools, click on the arrow next to the error and track the stack. Just before running Google maps code the function that throws error is that one.

Comment: It's very probable that somewhere you're sending an empty `buses` array. I'd start by checking if it's empty or has a length first...

Comment: right on man. thanks! fixed that. threw another error. but it's pretty much my pathetic understanding of json. can i reword this to give you credit? or should i close it?

Comment: Yah np, posted as answer. Btw as a tip _always_ check for null or empty values first otherwise you'll encounter these errors often because some functions are not meant to be run without a value or with an undefined value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`loadBusesIntoMap` seems to be the root of the problem. On Chrome developer tools, click on the arrow next to the error and track the stack. Just before running Google maps code the function that throws error is that one. It's very probable that somewhere you're sending an empty `buses` array. I'd start by checking if it's empty or has a `length` first...